# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<DerivedDataClass> to System.Collections.Generic.List<BaseDataClass>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I need to have an abstract class that contains a method to return a list of items that derive from a base class or interface. My code is below:

```
public abstract class Template
{
    //this should return the data to be used by the template
    public abstract List<BaseDataClass> GetDataSource(string sectionName);
}
```

I then have a derived data class that is used specifically with a derived template   class:

```
public class DerivedDataClass : BaseDataClass
{
     //some properties specific to the derived class
}
```

Then I have my main derived template class that inherits the abstract class. In here I want to return a list of DerivedDataClass back.

```
public class DerivedTemplate : Template
{
    public override List<BaseDataClass> GetDataSource(string sectionName)
    {
        List<DerivedDataClass> data = new List<DerivedDataClass>();

        //add some stuff to the list

        return data;
    }
 }
```

When I try to return that list I get a ‘cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Collections.Generic.List.

I realize that there is no direct conversion between these types, but I am unsure how I can accomplish this. In the future there will be many more derived template classes and derived data classes where I will need to use the GetDataSource function to get the list of data items.
 I think I’m over thinking this, but I have been at a wall for a little while now and am unsure of what direction I should go in.

Comment: Why do you need  to cast it back to its base and then recast it back to the derived type? That smells of polymorphism abuse. Downcasting (derived -> base) is fine , but upcasting (base -> derived) is often not what you should be doing. This suggests that you shouldn't have been downcasting to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` list needs to be of type `List<BaseDataClass>` rather than `List<DerivedDataClass>`.

For example, this will compile:

```
List<BaseDataClass> data = new List<DerivedDataClass>().Select(x => (BaseDataClass)x).ToList();
```

You can create a list and add items like so:

```
List<BaseDataClass> data = new List<BaseDataClass>();
data.Add(new DerivedDataClass());
```

Comment: I knew I was overthinking this, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>` is not co-variant related to `T`, so `List<Derived>` can't be casted to `List<Base>`.

Imagine `List<T>` would be covariant. You could write:

```cs
List<Base> bases = new List<Derived1>();
bases.Add(new Derived2());
```

Here `Derived2` and `Derived1` are different derived classes. This is an error, so `List` is not covariant related to `T`.

Then, what can you do?

#### `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant

```
var bases = new List<Base>(deriveds.AsEnumerable());
```

#### LINQ's `Cast`

```
var bases = deriveds.Cast<Base>()
                    .ToList();
```